# Force MenuBar to always open downward

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a MenuBar which opens downwards except when there isn't enough room to open it. For example, it may have 10 items but there's only enough room to display 4-5. Flex then tries to display the menu above the bar, which is completely off the screen. Is there some property or style I'm overlooking to always force it to open downward?

EDIT: Thought I'd give some clarification as to how I plan to circumvent the issue. If I can always force the menubar to be orientated downwards, I can make it into a scrollable menubar displaying only a few items at worst.

Comment: The nice thing about flex is you can override all the drawing and the measurement calculations of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a direct answer. However, the best resource I have ever seen on the menuBar component is here.

http://adobestudionews.net/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components_pt2.html

My guess is it is buried in the renderers.